# Adding '0' to binary

Tags: python, binary

How can i add number of '0' values to the left side of an existing binary type?

im getting the binary type by using the following:

```
 binary=bin(int(symbol))
```

where `symbol` is an int.

is there any way of doing that?

i want the result to be a string.

Comment: do you want the resulting number to be of binary type?

Comment: then just use concatenation because bin() returns a string object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no binary type, the result of `bin()` is a string.  Here is how you can add additional zeroes to the end of a string:

```
>>> bin(11)
'0b1011'
>>> bin(11) + '0000'
'0b10110000'
```

Since it sounds like you want to add the zeroes on the left side, I'm assuming that you are doing this so that the resulting strings are the same length regardless of the value for `symbol`.

One good way to do this is to use [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead of the `bin()` function, here is an example where there are always eight digits in the resulting string, and the `0b` prefix is still there as if you had used `bin()`:

```
>>> '0b{0:0>8b}'.format(3)
'0b00000011'
>>> '0b{0:0>8b}'.format(11)
'0b00001011'
```

Comment: i wanted it to be on the left side, but i guess its obvios how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want, adding '0' to where.

```
print bin(1<<8)
print bin(1).zfill(8).replace("b", "")
```

Hope that helps. ~Ben